# How to type a subclass of DelegateClass with Sorbet?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I want to type a class which inherits `DelegateClass(SomeClass)`. The method `Kernel#DelegateClass` receives a class, and returns a new class which delegates methods to the given class instance ([docs](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/stdlibs/delegate/Object.html#method-i-DelegateClass)).

Example ([playground](https://sorbet.run/#def%20some_complex_condition%28element%29%0A%20%20rand%20%3C%200.5%0Aend%0A%0Aclass%20ExtArray%20%3C%20DelegateClass%28Array%29%0A%20%20def%20find_by_some_complex_condition%0A%20%20%20%20find%20%7B%20%7Celement%7C%20some_complex_condition%28element%29%20%7D%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A)):

```rb
class ExtArray < DelegateClass(Array)
  def find_by_some_complex_condition
    find { |element| some_complex_condition(element) }
  end
end
```

First, Sorbet does not allow a superclass to be non-constant (https://srb.help/4002). So the first idea I came up with is using an alias.

First Try ([playground](https://sorbet.run/#def%20some_complex_condition%28element%29%0A%20%20rand%20%3C%200.5%0Aend%0A%0ADelegatedArray%20%3D%20DelegateClass%28Array%29%0A%0Aclass%20ExtArray%20%3C%20DelegatedArray%0A%20%20def%20find_by_some_complex_condition%0A%20%20%20%20find%20%7B%20%7Celement%7C%20some_complex_condition%28element%29%20%7D%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A)):

```rb
DelegatedArray = DelegateClass(Array)

class ExtArray < DelegatedArray
  def find_by_some_complex_condition
    find { |element| some_complex_condition(element) }
  end
end
```

But this is not type-checked too, because Sorbet disallows a superclass to be a class alias (https://srb.help/7003).

Then, how should I rewrite codes to be type-checked by Sorbet? It's OK to rewrite codes totally and remove `DelegateClass`, but delegations are necessary.

### Environment

- Ruby 3.0.5
- Sorbet 0.5.10751
- Tapioca 0.11.4
- macOS Ventura 13.3.1